Multiprotocol access on NetApp NFS4 volume
I have created NFS4 vserver and created a volume on NetApp OnTap, with Unix Security Style and want to mount it on Linux servers and provision access on windows laptop for SMB access on the shared folder. Its erring out saying 'Access denied' on windows laptop.
